# Was bedeutet "es beielet"?

Tags: dialect, meaning, swabian, swiss-german

Passend zur kalten Jahreszeit kommt mir wieder ein altes, schwäbisches Kinderlied in den Sinn, bei dem ich ein Wort nicht kenne:

#### Schwäbische Version:

> Es schneielet, es ***beielet***,
> Es goht an kalder Wend.
> Mädla ziaget Handschua o
> Ond Buaba laufed gschwend.

#### Schweizerdeutsche Version:

> Es schneielet, es ***beielet***,
> Es goht en kühle Wind.
> Und Maitli leget d'Hänsche-n-a
> Und d'Buebe laufet gschwind.

<sup>Quelle: [alemannische Wikipedia](http://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text:Es_schneielet)</sup>

#### Meine Übersetzung ins Hochdeutsch:

> Es schneit, es `______`,
> Es geht ein kühler Wind.
> Mädchen ziehen Handschuhe an
> und die Jungen laufen schnell.

Weiß jemand was *"es beielet"* oder evtl. auch "*beieln*" bedeutet?

Comment: Nur als Kommentar, da höchst unsicher: [häufig wird auf schweizerisch beili, biili „Biene“ verwiesen](http://content.stuttgarter-nachrichten.de/stn/page/2116898_0_9223_-was-bedeutet-eigentlich-es-beielet.html) - die Schneeflocken sollen bildlich wie die Bienen tanzen. Ein anderer Ansatz ist vielleicht das Verb „[beieln](http://drw-www.adw.uni-heidelberg.de/drw-cgi/zeige?db=drw&index=lemmata&term=beieln&darstellung=%DC)“ für „Glocke läuten“? Schlitten- oder Kirchenglocke vielleicht? Die übrigen Strophen geben leider keinen Hinweis.

Comment: Da man bei Gedichte so seine Freiheiten hat, schlage ich vor "beielet" mit "stöbert" zu übersetzen und statt "schnell" es bei "geschwind" zu belassen. Dann hast Du zwar zwei landschaftliche Ausdrücke drin, das Gedicht gewinnt aber dadurch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im [Idiotikon](http://www.idiotikon.ch/Register/faksimile.php?&band=4&spalte=911) findet sich dazu folgendes zu bijele, bei(j)jelen (nur Auszüge):

> leicht (in dünnen, kleinen Flocken) schneien, gelinde regnen. Schneit's dussen? Antwort: Nit recht, 's beijelet nummen en Bitzli.

Im weiteren wird dann auf den Kinderreim eingegangen:

> Es schneielet, es beielet durch en holi Tannen, wenn der Burenb'schisser malt, was der Bur het g'wannen (Rätsel vom tanzenden Mehlstaub in der Mühle) [...] Die tanzenden Schneeflocken werden mit schwärmenden Bienen verglichen. Wo das Wort nur noch im Kinderlied lebt, ist seine Bedeutung im Sprachbewusstsein verdunkelt; es haben volksetymologische Umdeutungen stattgefunden, die, zumal [...] der Reim kein Hinderniss bildete, auch seine Lautgestalt beeinflussten. So erklärt sich einerseits die Bedeutungs-Angabe "gelinde regnen", ferner "wehen" bei Roch. und Joh.Mey. 1866, andererseits die Ausweichung in bajelen, indem das Wort [...] als Diminutiv zu bajen gefasst wurde.

Die weiteren Einträge gehen auf Bei(j)eler, gebi(e)let usw. ein, die tatsächlich mit Bienen zu tun haben.

Eine Übersetzungsmöglichkeit wäre daher zum Beispiel "es wehet", auch wenn sich der Zusammenhang mit den Bienen wohl irgendwie auf das "Schwärmen" bezieht, das man aber vermutlich im Deutschen mehr schlecht als Recht in das Gedicht bekommt.

Answer (score 0):

Laut http://www.multi-deutsch.de/dreikoenigstag.html bedeutet beielet *eisregnen, frösteln*